# An explicit value for the identity column in table 'tableX' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am getting the error above saying that I cannot explicitly define the identity column without doing these things however, I am not trying to set the value of the identity column. I am merely trying to execute a basic insert statement using user input. I'm really stuck and need to get past this. Thoughts?

```
 Public Sub ExecuteSQL(ByVal sql As String)

    Using myConnection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString)
        myConnection.Open()
        Using cdmDatabaseCommand As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, myConnection)
            cdmDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

  Dim insertSpray As String = ""
  insertSpray = "INSERT INTO Spray VALUES ('" & sprayDate & "','" & timeStart & "','" & timeFinish & "','" & tankVolumeStart & "','" & tankVolumeFinish & "','" & comment & "','" & vehicleId & "','" & vehicleTime & "','" & siteType & "','" & area & "','" & applicatorOneId & "','" & applicatorTwoId & "','" & sprayLocationFeature & "','" & sprayStartLocationDescription & "','NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','" & sprayEndLocationDescription & "');"

  ExecuteSQL(insertSpray)
```

Comment: Well, you did not specify which columns and in which order you want to insert those values, so `sprayDate ` is likely trying to squeeze in to Identity column.  You should also use SQL Parameters.  Everything is not string/text is it?

Comment: This is very bad practice not to include `insert_list` into the `insert` statement. Any change in the table schema would crash the app.

Comment: How will this code work if your `comment` variable contains an apostrophe?  (Hint:  It won't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying a column-list, so SQL Server assumes you want to insert into all columns, in table-order.

You need to change your syntax to specify the names of the columns you're inserting into (and leave out the identity column, obviously):

```
insert into Spray (SprayDate, TimeStart, ...) 
values (...
```

Also note that your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters) attacks. You should look into using [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I'm not sure why I didn't think of doing that. Also thank you for the warning about SQL injection. I'm looking into parameterized queries now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly make the columns of table Spray without the identity column.

Something like this:

```
insertSpray = "INSERT INTO Spray(Column1, Column2,...) VALUES (Value1,Value2,..)"
```